# Why is git diff only working with option --cached?

Tags: git

If I execute `git diff file.php` then I don't get any response.

I always have to execute `git diff --cached file.php`.

Why is --cached not automatically executed and why do I have to do this?

I am using git version 2.17.0.windows.1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`git diff <file>` compares the file in **working dir** vs in **index**.

So if you already added the file (by `git add`) from **working dir** to **index**, then:

1. there is no diff between **working dir** and **index**.
2. but there is diff between the **current commit** (pointed by `HEAD`) and **index**, this diff is shown with the `--cached` option.

Answer (score 4):

The purpose of the `git diff` command is to compare the state of your index with your files present on your filesystem.
That of the `git diff --cached` command is to compare the state of your index with the commit your are pointing onto.

If you did changes to your file `file.php` that you did not already stage (using `git add`), then you should use `git diff` in order to see the changes.
But if you already did `git add` on this file, then a copy has been placed in your index, so to see the changes, you have to use the `git diff --cached` command.

Comment: You are right, there is no output after adding the file to the staging area! Thx!

Comment: "that you did not already commit" should probably read "that you did not already stage/add"

Comment: Thank you @ohlec, I typed too quicly ^^"